# How to make my Infinite images rotater able to be applied to many rotating boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, rotation

The Title name is not making clear what I want to do, but I will explain it here with some code.

A Javascript of the function which rotated absolute positioned images inside a div.
The problem what I am facing is, if I add more than one div -with class *rotating-item-wrapper*- with two images inside the function first rotates within the first div and then within the second. I want to rotate them separetly.

```
var InfiniteRotator =
    {
        init: function()
        {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            var initialFadeIn = 1000;

            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            var itemInterval = 5000;

            //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
            var fadeTime = 2500;

            //count number of items
            var numberOfItems = $('.rotating-item').length;

            //set current item
            var currentItem = 0;

            //show first item
            $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(initialFadeIn);

            //loop through the items
            var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
                $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeOut(fadeTime);

                if(currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                    currentItem = 0;
                }else{
                    currentItem++;
                }
                $('.rotating-item').eq(currentItem).fadeIn(fadeTime);

            }, itemInterval);
        }
    };

    InfiniteRotator.init();
```

Editted to this and this function never rotates images

```
<script>

        (function( $ ) {

        $.fn.InfiniteRotator = function(options) {

            var defaults = {
                //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
                initialFadeIn: 1000,
                //interval between items (in milliseconds)
                itemInterval: 5000,
                //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
                fadeTime: 2500,
                currentItem: 0
            };

            var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

            return this.each(function() {

                var numberOfItems = $(this).find('.rotating-item').length; 

                $(this).find('.rotating-item').eq(settings.currentItem).fadeIn(settings.initialFadeIn);

                //loop through the items
                var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
                    $(this).find('.rotating-item').eq(settings.currentItem).fadeOut(settings.fadeTime);

                    if(settings.currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                        settings.currentItem = 0;
                    }else{
                        settings.currentItem++;
                    }
                    $(this).find('.rotating-item').eq(settings.currentItem).fadeIn(settings.fadeTime);

                }, settings.itemInterval);
            });

        };

    }( jQuery ));
        $(window).load(function() { //start after HTML, images have loaded
            $('#rotating-item-wrapper1').InfiniteRotator();
        });
    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<section>
                <div class="imagesPanel" id="P1">   
                    <div class="rotating-item-wrapper" id="rotating-item-wrapper1">
                        <img class="rotating-item" src="Images/HotelM/1.jpg" alt="">
                        <img class="rotating-item" src="Images/HotelM/5.jpg" alt="">    
                    </div>
                    <img src="Images/HotelM/2.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="Images/HotelM/3.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="Images/HotelM/4.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="imagesPanel">
                    <img src="Images/rooms/1.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="Images/rooms/3.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="Images/rooms/5.jpg" alt="">
                    <img src="Images/rooms/6.jpg" alt="">
                </div>
```

CSS :

```
section .imagesPanel img{
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
    float: left;
}
.rotating-item-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 250px;
    height: 188px;
    border: 0;
    float: left;    
}
.rotating-item-wrapper .rotating-item {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create a basic jquery plugin in this way:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.InfiniteRotator = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            initialFadeIn: 1000,
            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            itemInterval: 5000,
            //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
            fadeTime: 2500,
            currentItem: 0
        };

        var settings = $.extend( {}, defaults, options );

        return this.each(function() {

            var numberOfItems = $(this).find('.rotating-item').length; 

            $(this).find('.rotating-item').eq(settings.currentItem).fadeIn(settings.initialFadeIn);

            //loop through the items
            var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function(){
                $(this).find('.rotating-item').eq(settings.currentItem).fadeOut(settings.fadeTime);

                if(settings.currentItem == numberOfItems -1){
                    settings.currentItem = 0;
                }else{
                    settings.currentItem++;
                }
                $(this).find('.rotating-item').eq(settings.currentItem).fadeIn(settings.fadeTime);

            }, settings.itemInterval);
        });

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

and call it like this `$('#mydivid').InfiniteRotator();` or with the options that you like

Comment: see the edit your code isnt working or im doing somethig wrong

Comment: i give you an approach on how to use a specific element... dont know if the fade process is working

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element to your init function which is what I believe you are tryinig to do. Basically the main element is the wrapper containing the rotating items. You can then use that element to traverse further down to do your animations.

I also noticed that the selector in your example was called `.DivID` but it is a class since it is using a `.` for the selctor... perhaps it should be an `#id` instead? I changed it to a class selector in the following example.

```
var InfiniteRotator = {
    init: function(element, options) {
        console.log(element.length);
        var defaults = {
            //initial fade-in time (in milliseconds)
            initialFadeIn: 1000,
            //interval between items (in milliseconds)
            itemInterval: 5000,
            //cross-fade time (in milliseconds)
            fadeTime: 2500,
            currentItem: 0
        };
        var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        var numberOfItems = $(element).find('.rotating-item');

        $(this).find('.rotating-item').eq(settings.currentItem).fadeIn(settings.initialFadeIn);

        //loop through the items
        var infiniteLoop = setInterval(function() {
            $(this).find('.rotating-item').stop().eq(settings.currentItem).fadeOut(settings.fadeTime);

            if (settings.currentItem == numberOfItems - 1) {
                settings.currentItem = 0;
            } else {
                settings.currentItem++;
            }
            $(this).find('.rotating-item').stop().eq(settings.currentItem).fadeIn(settings.fadeTime);

        }, settings.itemInterval);

    }
};

InfiniteRotator.init($(".divClass"), null);
```

Comment: ths is what i was looking for but when i have function(element) how do i call it later var numberOfItems = $(element).length;?

Comment: See edit. Basically the main element is the wrapper containing the rotating items in my example

Comment: see my edit need to make it infinite now otherwise it stops when it rotates all images

Comment: `setInterval(function, milliseconds)` should be doing that

Comment: but i guess i have to calculate execatly what milliseconds shold i write so it starts exactly after it ends

Comment: That's one way to do it or you can use the `.fadeout(duration, complete)` `complete` callback to trigger the next element to animate after the first one is done. That would require a few more code changes then the scope of this question is though.

Comment: I want this funtion  InfiniteRotator.init($(".divClass")); to be triggered again and again after it ends tried //setInterval(InfiniteRotator.init("#rotating-item-wrapper1"), 6000); and it does not starts again after it finishes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95363/discussion-between-georgi-antonov-and-chizzle).